# In Highchart, How to initialize a string values in data

Tags: javascript, sql, graph, charts, highcharts

I was trying to insert **series . data []** in string values,

But now it is in ordinary form **`data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]`**

If I give like this to string format

**`data: ['29.9', '71.5', '106.4', '129.2', '144.0', '176.0', '135.6', '148.5', '194.1', '95.6', '54.4']`**

it should work as like my example in fiddle, [**HERE IS MY EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6L6T/)

This is my Chart link, I want it to become like the example chart [**My Chart**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6L6T/2/)

Anyone Help is appreciated.

Comment: String format is not supported by Highcharts - required is number type. You probably have error in JS console explaining this..

Comment: @PawełFus: Thanks friend, Is there any other way to get the solution for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use numbers or parse strings to numbers using `parseFloat()`:

```
    series: [{
        data: ['29.9', '71.5', '106.4', '129.2', '144.0', '176.0', '135.6', '148.5', '194.1', '95.6', '54.4'].map(function (a) {
            return parseFloat(a);
        })
    }]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J6L6T/1/

Comment: I tried your solution that is working only on hand coded values.But i want dynamic solution.Now here is my chart .In that var avg is changed every time.

And loop count also change any time.In this situation how to handle this 
 for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
              {
              
              rangeravg.push(avg);
            
              }

Comment: And what is wrong with your chart? It works fine? Anyway, you said you have values as strings, not all data is a string, it's huge difference.